# What is the equivalent code of a Unicode character

Tags: unicode

For example I know that ***2018*** is the hexadecimal equivalent of ***left single quotation mark***, and I have the following questions:

- 1: Is there a way to input the Unicode name to Emacs and get the equivalent code, and vice versa?
- 2: Is there a way to list them all?

I know I can list the Unicode names using **C-x 8 RET TAB**, but this list doesn't show the equivalent codes (preferably in decimal).

Comment: `2018` is the **hexadecimal** value for LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, not the decimal value. Are you sure your question meets your actual requirements?

Comment: @phils thank's for pointing that out, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. @paulie4 pointed out command `describe-char`.
2. Command **`apropos-char`** from library [`apu.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/apu.el) prompts you for an apropos pattern to match against Unicode character names.  The pattern is a regexp or parts of the names to match. Then it shows you the characters, their names, and their code points (decimal and hex). See [Apropos Unicode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AproposUnicode).

Answer (score 2):

You can use **M-x describe-char** to get info on the character under your cursor (see http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_n_unicode.html). Since you know **C-x 8 RET** can be used to enter a Unicode character using its name, I think that should answer your first question, but I do not know if there's a way to list them all by code points.

Note: I just looked at the help for **insert-char**, and it says you can enter the code point to insert using decimal by prefixing it with `#10r` :

> - As a code point with a radix specified with #, e.g. #o21430
>     (octal), #x2318 (hex), or #10r8984 (decimal).

Comment: n.b. `C-u C-x =` is the standard key binding to show you the `describe-char` information (and plain `C-x =` shows some minimal details in the echo area).